# Методы синхронизации клиента и сервера веб приложения (сайта ...)

Tags: веб-программирование, клиент-сервер, веб-служба, синхронизация

Я обучаюсь верстке, js jquery на веб-студии. Раз в месяц у нас митинги - каждый делает доклад, презентации по разным темам. У меня та что в заголовке - связано с веб сайтами. Клиент - браузер, сервер - какой то сервер.

Какие есть методы или технологии, или сервисы синхронизации клиента и сервера веб приложения?
Нужно только название, остальное загуглю.

Comment: напиши в вопросе что подразумевается под "клиент"? и стек технологий напиши

Comment: Я обучаюсь верстке, js jquery на веб-студии. Раз в месяц у нас митинги - каждый делает доклад, презентации по разним темам. У меня та что в заголовке - связано с веб сайтами. Клиен - браузер; сервер - какой то сервер. И сорри за неполную картину - описал как мог. Спасибо

Comment: перенес этот комментарий в вопрос, так он станет понятней

Comment: Чего собственно им (клиенту и серверу веб приложения) синхронизировать-то?

Answer (score 1):

Ну так стандартные, определенные в протоколе HTTP: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE...
Подробнее можно посмотреть тут: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616

Comment: а по-моему ему нужен рассказ про ajax-websocket-longpolling-etc